# Как подключиться к виртуальной машине, работающей с помощью Hyper-v?

Tags: hyper-v

Собственно я полный 0 =) Имею Win server 2012 R2. Установлен диспетчер Hyper-v. Работают 5 машин. В диспетчере двойным кликом открываю нужную машину и всё работает.
Смотрю IP адрес:
[image: ip вм]

В основной локальной сети именно такие адреса. Запускаю cmd на этом же сервере и пингую эту виртуальную машину. Получаю:

[image: Пинг с сервера]

Далее смотрю что вообще за сетевые интерфейсы есть на этом сервере.

[image: Интерфейсы на сервере]

Все GR - это мультиплексоры. Адресов нет. Все SW - Это виртуальные коммутаторы (как я понял).
VEthernet#1 выглядит так:

[image: vEthernet#1]

Заодно это и адрес самого сервера Hyper-v.
Второй выглядит так:

[image: vLAN#2]

Остальные элементы вообще пустые. Ни адресов, ничего вообще.

Нажал значок сети:
[image: Сети]

Не понял что за ужас и почему их 4.

Вот параметры нужной мне виртуальной машины:

[image: парам1]

[image: парам2]

[image: парам3]

Далее параметры виртуальных коммутаторов:

[image: к которому подключена моя виртуальная машина]

По ролям вот так:
[image: Роли]

Исходя из всего этого кошмара. Как подключиться по SSH к этой виртуальной машине? И желательно не с сервера, а с другого ПК, который относится к сети 192.168.1.Х. Что прописать в Putty и WinSCp? МОжет команда с маршрутом нужна? Какая?

Сама эта машина доступна в браузере. Там пару веб страниц.

С остальными машинами люди работают, правда там веб приложения. В браузере у них работаю приложения и  ip тот, который у вирт. машины.

Пробовал пинговать другую машину. Тоже нет ответа.